# How to remove box aspect from subplot in figure Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an issue with the subplot in my figure. Initially I had the aspect equal and adjustable='box' but even if I removed this line , each subplot keep their box ratio. I tried many things such as changing my ylimit but nothing works. My problem is with my figure named fig3.My 12 y values in all subplot are in range 0-1 and for the x axis , the range on each subplot are okay but the y axis is the same as the x

```
fig3,((ax1, ax2,ax3,ax4), (ax5,ax6,ax7,ax8)) = plt.subplots(2,4)
ax_list=[ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6,ax7,ax8]
liste_couleur=['c','m','r','g','k','y','b','saddlebrown']
fig3.suptitle('uk versus Tk pour des valeurs de densité')
for i in np.arange(0,8,1):
    ax_list[i].set_title('densitée='+str(np.round(p[i],0)))
    ax_list[i].set_xlabel('Tk')
    ax_list[i].set_ylabel('uk')
    ax_list[i].plot(Tk[i,:],uk[i,:],liste_couleur[i],'.',markersize=8,linestyle='None')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('question_2_fig3')

plt.show()
```

[question_2_fig3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xGvE.png)

Comment: You may want to improve the question. But from what I understand, the problem seems to be with '.' in the line of code that plots the data. Change it to marker='.' and that probably solves your problem.

Comment: You might want to change the figsize e.g. `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,4,figsize=16,6)`. Matplotlib just tries to fill the available space. By the way, you can use `ax_list = axs.flatten()` to get the axes in a single list.